# How to load specific data from JSON file based on ID

Tags: jquery, json, find

I want to load specific data from JSON file based on ID. I am showing the list of thumbnail images data below based on the JSON file, and then i want to load large image on click event.

You can see my code for reference. I just want to know how i can find the large image in JSON file based on the ID from the list on click event.

For example: I want get the value of "largeimg" from JSON file based on the 'name' value. in my HTML, "<'li id="Red">" I want if users click on this "<'li'>" then based on the id = "Red" should match the "name = Red" in JSON file and get value "/imgs/redlarge.png" from "largeimg" from JSON file

## JSON DATA

```
{
 "colors": [
  {
   "name": "Red",
   "thumb": "/imgs/redthumb.png",
   "largeimg": "/imgs/redlarge.png"
  },
  {
   "name": "Blue",
   "thumb": "/imgs/bluethumb.png",
   "largeimg": "/imgs/bluelarge.png"
  }
 ]
 }
```

## HTML

```
<div class="preview">
 <!-- Show data from JSON file based on ID -->
</div>
<div class="list">
 <ul class="colors">
 </ul>
</div>
```

## JQUERY

```
$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {
 $.each(data.colors, function (index, value) {
  $('.colors').append("<li id='item-"+this.name+"'>"+this.thumb+"</li>");
 });
});
$('.list li').click(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. [on method document][1]

for dynamically added html you must use on method for attach event handlers as following. define a global colors variable for json data for search on data.

```
var colors;

$.getJSON('data.json', function (data) {

    colors = data.colors;

    $.each(data.colors, function (index, value) {
        $('.colors').append("<li id='item-"+this.name+"'>"+this.thumb+"</li>");
    });
});

$('.list li').click(function(){

    var name = $(this).attr('id');

    var found;
    $.each(colors, function(index, item){
        if(item.name == name){
            found = item;
        }
    })
});

if(found){
    console.log(found.largeimg);
}
```

Comment: I just want to get value from JSON file based on the ID on click event. My on click event is working but i want to get value from JSON file. Please see my updated question above with example

Answer (score -1):

It does not look like file size is information provided to you in the JSON data file. For this reason, I am unsure how you would plan to sort by size. Unless, you were content with using "largeimg" as the file size. In this case, it may help to use a JSON to Java class creator to do this for you.

Here is one: https://timboudreau.com/blog/json/read

You may need to search for a new one, but generally it allows you to interpret your JSON data and access specific data sections (ie. Image size)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the original poster is trying to achieve. It's not about file size.